# From any ten naturals, find some numbers whose sum is divisible by $ 10.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $A \subset \mathbb N $ such that $|A| = 10.$

Then prove that there exists a non-empty $B \subseteq A$ such that the sum of the elements in $B$ is divisible by $10.$

How to go to the gist of this question?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, what have you tried to solve this?

Comment: $Please$ give any $hints$ to start. However i m concentrating about the unit place of numbers whose sum gives a number whose unit digit is 0...

Comment: Pardon... $B \subseteq A \subset \mathbb N$

Comment: Two quick puzzles: What is the fewest possible subsets that sum to a multiple of ten; what is the most possible?

Comment: @Michael Could you please explain the puzzles little precisely?

Comment: You know there is at least one subset that sums to a multiple of ten.  Can there be just one subset, or must there be more?  And, can all subsets sum to multiples of ten, or not?

Comment: @Michael. There are at  most 10$C_2$ subsets that sums to a multiple of ten.It happens only when all the remainders, of dividing $a_1$, $a_1 + a_2, …, a_1 + … + a_{10}$ by $10$, are same.(thanks @k.stm).

Comment: @Michael if all remainders are distinct, then some should be 0. Then there is at least one subset that sums to a multiple of 10. Is this correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $A = \{a_1, …, a_{10}\}$, consider the remainders of dividing $a_1$, $a_1 + a_2, …, a_1 + … + a_{10}$ by $10$. What does it mean if you get a remainder twice? What happens if you don’t?

Comment: Getting a remainder twice will lead to one among $a_i$ is divisible by 10.

Comment: @yazhini Not quite. Imagine $a_1$ having the same remainder as $a_1 + a_2 + a_3$.

Comment: Thanks, Here $B=\{a_3,a_2\}$ satisfies the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a_1, a_1+a_2, \dots, a_1+\dots+a_9$. If two have the same residue, we get $a_j+\dots+a_k\equiv0\mod10$ for some $i,j$. If not, if $a_{10}$ is $0\mod10$, we are done, otherwise by adding it to one of the previous sums we will hit a $0\mod10$ (by the Pigeonhole Principle).