# Why is there always a subset of $n$ given numbers that sums up to a multiple of $n$?

Tags: number-theory

Show that in a list of $n$ elements $(a_1,.....,a_n)$ (where for every $i = 1,...,n$ $a_i$ can take a value between $0$ and $n-1$) we can always find a sublist of $k$ elements such that their sum is divisible by $n$.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1214068/42242).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From any ten naturals, find some numbers whose sum is divisible by $ 10.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214068/from-any-ten-naturals-find-some-numbers-whose-sum-is-divisible-by-10)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you want $k\geq1$. There are $n+1$ values
$$s_r:=\sum_{j=1}^r a_j\qquad(0\leq r\leq n)$$
modulo $n$. Therefore there are $p$ and $q$ with $0\leq p < q\leq n$ such that $s_p=s_q$ modulo $n$. It follows that
$$\sum_{j=p+1}^q a_j=0\qquad({\rm mod}\ n)\ .$$